# Can a 4 prong welder run off a 3 prong outlet?

Tags: adapter

My Millermatic 350 welder (runs 480v or 240v) has a 4 prong L16-30 plug and I have a 3 prong 6-50 outlet. Can I run an adapter from the 3 prong outlet to the 4 prong machine?

Essentially, can I use the welder without a neutral wire attached?

Also If I can do that, I have 6/3 wire so it has 2 hot, a neutral and a bare ground. If I skip using a neutral, should I use the bare wire or the spare insulated (the neutral) wire as the ground?

**UPDATE**

I plugged the adapter into the outlet and the welder into the adapter in and the 6-50 male plug on the adapter started smoking. Opened up the male plug and it looks like the wire on the ground prong is the most melted.

I switched the welder on but it didn't turn on at all, the plug just smoked

Advice? I have no idea what may have happened.

Also I tested the hot to hot on the 4 prong cord end of the adapter and got 220v and then tested the hot to ground and got 110v. Should I be getting voltage on the ground?

Comment: Would say no, maybe if it was three prong welder to four.  Does welder have 120v outlet?

Comment: What is the model number of the welder? Some can run off of 240 but not all. You would not use the neutral if it could run off of 240 hot, hot, ground.

Comment: It's a millermatic 350 and it runs 480 and 240.

Comment: When your adapter's grounding prong was damaged, where did you have your workpiece clamp positioned? It's possible to blow out the grounding lead on a correctly wired welder if you put the workpiece lead in the wrong place...

Comment: The workpiece clamp was hanging on the welder not touching anything.

Comment: @IanF -- hm...that could be part of the problem if you actually were striking an arc with the workpiece clamp unhooked...

Comment: @Threephase -- ?? To me that doesn't make sense. Also it's a mig welder so there is no current running through the gun or ground clamp until you pull the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

According to the millermatic 350 this welder is a 240v hot,hot ground connection the red connection is not used. On page 23 of the manual I found online.
This makes sense since it is also a 3 phase 480 machine the voltage to ground would be 277 so any control voltage is made from the source voltage.

L1,L2 black , white and ground green.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. Turns out the diagram I was looking at was inverted and I had one of the hots and the unused neutral mixed up.

Comment: And you did not die, did your welder survive?

Comment: Yes it did thank God.